# Find Duplicate Entry In Database - PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want to check if the same `token` is present in the database before executing any other queries. For this, I fetched all rows from the database table and stored in an `array`.

```
if (isset($_POST['token']) && !empty($_POST['token'])){
    $token_raw = $_POST['token'];
}

$sql_result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM used_tokens");
if ($sql_result != NULL) {
    while ($sql_result_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        $used_tokens = [$sql_result_rows['used_tokens']];
        $date_used = [$sql_result_rows['date_used']];
    }
}
if ($token_raw === $used_tokens) { //I think something is wrong here...
    echo 'Incorrect Token Used.';
}
else {
    $submit_sql = "INSERT INTO used_tokens (used_tokens) VALUES ('$token_raw')";
    if ($connection->query($submit_sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $submit_sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    }
    //$sqli = mysqli_query($connection, $conn);
}
```

I think I am mistaking the `array` part by checking `if ($token_raw === $used_tokens)`. Please suggest me best practice for this and also where I am making mistake.

Comment: You don't need to store all tokens in an array, just use the [`WHERE`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_where_clause.htm) clause, and check if your token is found in the db. One more thing, what type is `$token_raw`? It is just that, assuming that your token is a string, `$token_raw === $used_tokens` is very wrong, you are comparing a string to an array

Comment: `$used_tokens` is just also an array of the last token on the database, you would normally do `$used_tokens[]` to add an item to a list.  BUT you should use a WHERE clause as Swellar pointed out.

Comment: just use UNIQUE flag in your database so it can't be duplicated

Comment: `$token_raw` is a string. Thanks for your suggestions, It solved my problem.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is open to an SQL injection attack.  Please check how you generate SQL queries (NEVER use unvalidated user inputs to build an SQL string!  Try to use prepared statements wherever possible and ALWAYS validate/sanitise user input before using it for anything!)

Answer (score -1):

So far
`$token_raw` - is a token string
`$used_tokens` - is an array of used tokens

If you want to know, was this token used before, then you have to use `in_array()` function.

`if (in_array($token_raw, $used_tokens)) ...`

But, the idea is not good in general.
You shouldn't select all tokens to store them in the query.
Because, if data set will grow large - this can become slow operation and can take much memory.

You should edit your SQL query, by adding a condition `WHERE`.

Example:

```
$sql = '`SELECT * FROM `used_tokens` WHERE `used_tokens` = "%s"';
mysqli_query(
    $connection,
    sprintf(
        $sql,
        mysqli_real_escape_string(
            $connection,
            $token_raw
        )
    )
)
```

;